# Build Cordova Browser for production

Tags: apache, cordova, cordova-plugins, phonegap, cordova-3

I have an Apache Cordova app which I have deployed for both ios and android. But i want to deploy it for my web server i.e. I want to deploy it on my server live so users can access it using their browsers. How can I go about it?
for android its  `cordova build android --release` but for browser, I don't know which command to use for this operation.

Comment: Did you found any solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

For browser it is simply

```
cordova build browser --release
```

Comment: This command seems to do nothing.

Comment: Normally for browser there's nothing to build, unless you have some custom hooks. Or do you want to run the browser?

Comment: I figured it out. Even for the browser platform a build step is necessary, otherwise how would plugins be included and where would `cordova.js` come from? After running this command, the build will be ready at `./platforms/browser/www/`, which is the directory to be deployed. It would just be nice if the command would print what it has built, just like Android/iOS do.